# Windows Batch-File to execute n other batch-files in parallel

Tags: windows, multithreading, batch-file, ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg to convert video files. The codec I'm encoding with is single-threaded. There are a lot of video files to convert, so instead of using multithreaded encoding I can simply encode multiple video files with 1 thread each.

To automate the encoding I use the follow commands in a .bat:

```
SET maindir=%~dp0
FOR /r /d %%f in (*) do pushd "%%f" & Call %maindir%convert-with-ffmpeg.bat & popd
```

This calls "convert-with-ffmpeg.bat" sequentially`to convert each file/folder in the main dir.

What would my .bat file have to look like if I want to do this in parallel (say, 12 times) until there are no more folders left to process?

EDIT: Let me be clear that I want to LIMIT the amount of running processes at 12. When a .bat is done, I want the main .bat to start a new process until all files are converted (100+).

Comment: Call out to another function within the batch file. Use tasklist and the find command to count the occurences of FFMPEG that are running.  If it is less than 12 then return to the main command which will be the FOR command so that it can start another process.  IF 12 are running then have it continue to loop in the called function.

Answer (score 0):

Use start instead of call.   It will not wait for the other .bat file to complete:

```
SET maindir=%~dp0
FOR /r /d %%f in (*) do pushd "%%f" & start %maindir%convert-with-ffmpeg.bat & popd
```

Comment: I want to limit the amount of running .bat file to 12. When one is done, another one should be started.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in no way proficient regarding batch-programming, but I did it (in another context) like this (shamelessly stolen):

```
FOR /r /d %%f in (*) do start /b CMD /C "%maindir%\convert-with-ffmpeg.bat %%f"
```

[Start reference](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

Then convert-with-ffmpeg.bat would contain:

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b %1\*.mpeg') do ffmpeg -i "%%f" ...
```

Maybe I'm wrong but I tested it by this in convert-with-ffmpeg.bat:

```
echo %time:~0,11% Uhr
sleep 2
```

[Time reference](http://ss64.com/nt/time.html)

The timestamps were nearly identical.

**Edit in response to comment (granted an immature solution)**

An alternative version to start the second script only a specified amount of times:

```
SET maindir=%~dp0
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
SET count=0

FOR /r /d %%f in (*) DO (
START /b CMD /C "%maindir%\convert-with-ffmpeg.bat %%f"
SET /a count+=1
IF !count!==12 (GOTO :EOF)
)
```

[For reference](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

Maybe I am gone off track here. Batch wouldn't be my first choice when confronted with this task. Maybe consider using python or java. You'll find they offer a plethora of solutions for concurrency-programming and process execution.

Comment: This will start a .bat for every single folder in this case that would be more than 100 files and will for sure cause problems. How do I limit the amount of .bat processes open to 12 (amount of cores I have)?